# How to salvage evil loot?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, magic-items

I'm currently running a [premade scenario](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Crown_of_the_Kobold_King) for Pathfinder where the author gives out rather powerful magic items for character levels 3, but they're almost the only treasure to be had in the scenario.

Thing is, their history and sometimes the way they are used seem, to me, inadequate for a mostly good-aligned party. One is a +1 dagger which true powers are revealed by ripping someone's heart with it (and then consuming said heart). The other one isn't as gruesome, but is an accessory that good people probably wouldn't wear (blood-stained spiky crown).

As the GM, I'm wondering what to do with these items as I get the feeling they won't see actual use by the party, and would probably be hard to sell, both considering their high price and the rare kind of potential buyers they may lure.

I'm interested in both mechanical and story aspects for this. Is it possible to recraft items, cleanse evil magic items and such? It probably wouldn't be a bad thing if this led to further stories, but I don't want the party to wait forever to get proper loot either. Any other tricks to dealing with this?

Comment: Also requesting help to make that footnote link work...

Comment: Not sure what URL you were hoping to use, so I linked to the Pathfinder wiki page for it.

Comment: @Ellesedil: I didn't realize it *needed* a URL, thus why it didn't work apparently. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Jesus was Good, and wearing a "blood-stained, spiked crown" is one of the things he's known for. "Good" isn't about your fashion style.

Comment: There are rules for deconstructing magic items to recover a portion of their power for crafting use.  Crafting-specialized classes get to do this for free, but I've always allowed other classes to take it as a feat.  Also, in a suitably large town, the players could probably trade the items to such a magic crafter for a discount on purchases.

Comment: @Perkins: are these from the core rulebook or somewhere else? I don't remember seeing such things in my books so far.

Comment: @leokhorn  Artificers (Introduced in Eberron) would be the obvious class that can do it.  I've run across a couple of others, but don't remember which ones off the top of my head.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're the DM, that means that you can change the scenario however you want, and specify how the magic items work however you want.

There are a lot of possible solutions, some of which you've mentioned. Personally I'd probably just reskin the evil-looking crown. The magic part of it could be a circlet, but the last owner added spiky bloody bits because they were Evil with a capital E.

For the dagger, you could have some sort of good order of priests or something of that nature offer the PCs a magic item of similar value in exchange, so they can destroy the evil item. Alternatively, you could simply Rule 0 it to change the requirements for using the dagger to being used in defense of the innocent, or something in that vein. Further possibilities include adding some other equivalent magic item as loot, and making the dagger disappear or lose its magic as soon as its wielder is killed.

In terms of players 'fixing' or 'cleaning' loot they've already found, you can create holy shrines that can remove the darkness from items (a nice example would be a spring or other water source, as immersion of items could be used as a cure).

Comment: That isn't rule 0, that's just deciding to drop loot that works differently. (which might be a pretty good idea)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Rule 0 (as I understand it) is that the DM is the final authority and can change any rules if necessary, including how items work. But I guess you could argue that Rule 0 only applies to rules, rather than the whole game.

Comment: Rule zero is everything the DM ever does in that case. But mainly it's just about the DM getting to day how the rules work.

Comment: +1 for good priests trading for the items so they can purify or destroy them. Maybe even add in a counter-offer from someone who's secretly working for the *next* bad guy.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Rule 0 is quite explicitly not only about the DM getting to say how the rules work, it is also about the DM getting to throw specific rules out altogether.

Answer (score 22):

Magic items that the group has to ponder using and may raise moral issues with a well-roleplayed group? I don't see the problem with that. That sounds ***awesome***.

If you're running the game in a way that makes Wealth By Level important, then just throw in some other treasure alongside these goodies to make up the difference. You won't break anything. (Not following WBL won't break anything anyway except for fragile campaign designs, so minor tweaks are certainly not going to break things.)

Disregard the dagger's "true" powers (which your PCs will probably never use), and treat it like a plain dagger +1 for the purpose of calculating the value of the treasure. If the players *do* actually go all heart-eating maniac and unlock its true potential, then sure they've got a higher-powered item now than what is "balanced", but they're paying for it by being heart-eating anti-heroes. Again, awesome.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph: Yea. That depends a *lot* on the group. It can be really awesome. In the majority of groups I personally have encountered, "recipe for disaster" isn't quite a strong enough term.